# Startup titles for two co-founders where one is the official company director

Tags: colleagues, startup, job-description, title, company

I've just cofounded a tech startup company with a friend. Our roles are currently ambiguous and we will probably both be working on similar stuff to get everything off the ground. However, I am the majority shareholder and official director of the company as we agree that I will commit more "effort" to the company.

We both like the ambiguity of "co-founder" as a title since it doesn't imply specific responsibilities etc. However, I would still like to subtly indicate that I am "in charge" through my title without sounding arrogant.

We don't like CEO and COO as it implies responsibilities and not just the heirarchy. Does anyone have any thoughts on what the two ambiguous titles could be that still imply a heirarchy? Is there a standard that I have missed? Founding Director and Cofounder? Cofounder and Director and Cofounder?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Managing Director is precise and not pretentious. I don't see cofounder as a job title at all. It's just a description of an event.

Comment: In the case of me being managing director, what would my friend be? “X” Director wouldn’t make sense for him since he will basically be fulfilling similar duties to me but to a lesser extent. Maybe one week I’ll be focussing on marketing while he focusses on sales and vice a versa. We are both still working full time until we get the company to a “sufficient” stage.

Comment: Why do you want to indicate that you are in charge? Does he report to you or do you report to each other? And are you sure you want to keep the responsibilities for each of you vague?

Comment: Ultimately, we’ve got an array of opportunities. We don’t know exactly which ones will take off, and each have their own priorities/requirements that would effectively govern what’s done on a day-day basis. Maybe we just go with co founder and co founder until the business is more clearly defined, at which point, concrete responsibilities and titles should be relatively self evident.

Comment: If I were your co-founder, this question would raise a massive "red flag"... Both of you did not achieve anything yet in the new startup, if I understood you right, but you already want to be seen as the "more important" of the two co-founders... First you need to create your business THEN you need to consider titles. The other way around makes me ask myself: Why is this important to him? And I don't like the possible answers...

Comment: Titles are meaningless at this point. The only thing that matters is who is ultimately in charge, who owns 51% and who owns 49%. There has to be one person who has the last word. You also need a formal agreement on how to break up the company when he disagrees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Our roles are currently ambiguous and we will probably both be working on similar stuff to get everything off the ground.

It doesn't sound like you actually have any proper roles or hierarchy at all. If you had defined roles, then it would be common for one of you to be the Managing Director, and the other (junior) one to be the Technical Director, or Operations Director, or whatever it is that they actually do.

But since you've not worked out what you, you can't have meaningful job titles.

> However, I would still like to subtly indicate that I am "in charge" through my title without sounding arrogant.

To be completely honest, it does sound arrogant. From what you've said you don't have an actual business (since you both have full time jobs), you don't have any idea what the two of you do, and you don't have a clear direction for where you're going. But you're still worried about getting a fancy title that makes you sound like the boss, and making sure that everyone knows that you're "above" your co-founder.

What exactly are you hoping to achieve with your job title, other than making yourself feel more important? How do you think it will affect your co-founder's ability to do whatever it is they're doing?

If I'm dealing with a two person startup, and I know that there's a *Supreme Director Who's Actually In Charge*, and a *Junior Co-Founder*, then why would I bother talking to the junior person? They're not going to be able to make the decisions on their own, and I'll be wondering why I'm getting fobbed off with the junior rather than being able to talk to the person in charge.

The inevitable effect of trying to give yourself a title that makes it clear that you're *above* your partner in the hierarchy is that you also make it clear that they're *below* you - which is going to make it much harder for them to effectively represent the company.

---

Once you have a real business, defined responsibilities and some employees, then you can start worrying about what job titles you both have. Until then, just call yourself both Directors or Founders, and if anyone specifically asks you about it, you can tell them that you're the majority shareholder.

Comment: Yeah that’s what I’ve decided to do. Refer to both of ourselves simply as cofounders until roles become clearer when the company takes off more

Answer (score 8):

The titles are not that important.

What **IS** important is to have a contract stating what happens for day to day responsibilities AND if the start-up fails ie who will need to do what and the liabilities etc.

Too many stories about how things go wrong when there is no contract.

Comment: Can this reside in the shareholders agreement or founders letter?

Comment: You can chisel it on stone as long as it is what you both agree.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: @HarryStuart, And even before you do the contract, you should write one of these documents: https://www.amazon.com/Partnership-Charter-Start-Right-Business/dp/0738208981/ A partnership is like a marriage. You need to be extremely careful about starting one.

Answer (score 0):

- Managing co-founder
- Co-founder

As simple as that.